# Multiple colours for data points with scatterplot in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

so my assignment is to basically get to the graph below. 
The data is from a data frame, in which there are certain values that have been marked as NA.
As such, my code is as follows:

```
> plot(temp,ozone,
+      xlab = "temperature",
+      ylab = "ozone",
+      col = ifelse(which(ozone>100), "red", "orange",),
+      pch = 17)
```

However I am now getting an error:

```
"Error in ifelse(which(ozone > 100), "red", "orange", ) : 
  unused argument (alist())
```

I would appreciate any feedback/pointers on what has gone wrong. 
I have previously also tried something like:

```
highlevels <- which(ozone>100)
lowlevels <- which(ozone<100)
col = c("red","orange")[highlevels,lowlevels]
```

However clearly that didnt work as well...
[image: Goal]

Comment: Have you tried `ozone` instead of `ozones`?

Comment: wow, didn't catch that - thank you! Sadly, the error still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave out the `which` and wrap it in another `ifelse` is one option:

```
plot(temp, ozone,
     xlab = "temperature",
     ylab = "ozone",
     col = ifelse(ifelse(!is.na(ozone), ozone, 0) > 100, "red", "orange"),
     pch = 17)
```

Otherwise, functions like `tidyr::replace_na` or `dplyr::coalesce` can help you if you're using those libraries.

Another option could be to subset all variables to those non-missing.

Yet another is setting

```
col =  c("red", "orange")[(ozone > 100) + 1]
```

but that is kinda tricky.

Comment: Thank you all! Didn't realize that such a tiny mistake can basically ruin the entire code :(

Comment: @AndersEllernBilgrau, I don't understand how does your edit work: ```[(ozone>100)+1]```, is that basically saying that everything > 100 + 1 will be red?

Comment: @aislinx No, `(ozone > 100)` is a logical vector (possibly with NAs), and the addition of `1` to that gives a vector of 1s, 2s, and NAs as `TRUE` and `FALSE` are considered `1` and `0` respectively. The ones and twos are then used to subset the character vector of colours. Try `(c(1, 2, NA) > 1) + 1` and it's parts. So it is just some hacky subsetting.

Comment: Oh ok! I didn't know that subsets could be used in this way. Thank you for your explanation!